# Regex not matching when used with PHP

Tags: php, regex

Given a fairly simple regex, I'd like to match a text between to delimiters:

```
___MANUAL_TICKET___

###_CLIENT_START_###
TEST
###_CLIENT_END_###

###_PROBLEM_START_###
TEST2
###_PROBLEM_END_###

###_EMAIL_START_###
xyz@test.com
###_EMAIL_END_###
```

To get the `client` I am using this regex:

> `###_CLIENT_START_###\s(.*?)\s###_CLIENT_END_###`

which works as seen [HERE](https://regexr.com/4h9sq).

But when I use it in my PHP Code it does not find any matches:

`preg_match('@###_CLIENT_START_###\s(.*?)\s###_CLIENT_END_###@', $source, $matches);`

(tried different regex delimiter such as `/` and `~`, same result)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the dot (.) by default matches any symbol but the line feed ([See the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)).

Since you have multiple line input, you need to use the `PCRE_DOTALL` option, which can be enabled just adding symbol `s` at the very end of the pattern

```
preg_match('@###_CLIENT_START_###\s(.*?)\s###_CLIENT_END_###@s', $source, $matches);
                                                             ^ here
```

Comment: perfect, thank you!